# Ошибка в коде: OpenCV(4.1.0) Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0])

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

Когда запускаю программу, Visual Studio показывает мне код из файла mat.inl.hpp, где говорит, что некое исключение не было обработано.
Вот код:

```
Mat src = imread("C:/Users/Archi/Desktop/game.png");
Mat hsv = Mat(src.cols, src.rows, 8, 3);
vector<Mat> splitedHsv = vector<Mat>();
cvtColor(src, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
split(hsv, splitedHsv);

const int ORANGE_MIN = 10;
const int ORANGE_MAX = 15;

for (int y = 0; y < hsv.cols; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < hsv.cols; x++)
    {
        int H = static_cast<int>(splitedHsv[0].at<uchar>(x, y)); // тон
        int S = static_cast<int>(splitedHsv[1].at<uchar>(x, y)); // интесивность
        int V = static_cast<int>(splitedHsv[2].at<uchar>(x, y)); // яркость

        if ((V < 97) || (H < ORANGE_MIN) || (H > ORANGE_MAX))
        {
            src.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[0] = 255;
            src.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[1] = 255;
            src.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[2] = 255;
        }
    }
}

Mat tmp;

imshow("All сells", src);
imshow("Only one", tmp);

waitKey(0);

destroyAllWindows();
```

[image: Вот та самая ошибка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если в C:/Users/Archi/Desktop/game.png размер по горизонтали и вертикали будет совпадать, то код будет работать. Ошибка здесь

```
for (int y = 0; y < hsv.cols; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < hsv.cols; x++)
```

в одном  с циклов должно быть rows, а не cols

Comment: Блин, а я и не заметил. Спасибо вам огромное!